# Python : make a plot with "day of the year"

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a big dataframe with dates (datetime format) and items with category:

Ex:

> Date ; Category ; Item
>
> 2015-05-13 23:53:00 ; A ; B

I would like to make a plot of the number of items by "day of the year" (how many items on Christmas days, not depending on the year)

So far I've created a new column 'DayOfYear' containing "month-day" in as string form (ex: 12-24) and I have grouped by this attribute to count the number of items

```
df = df[['Category','DayOfYear']].groupby(['DayOfYear']).count()
```

It gives me a table which is not far from what I would like:

> ```
> > DayOfYear; Category 
> > 1-1 ; 1801
> > 1-10 ; 4829
> > 1-11 ; 4971
> > 1-12 ; 3964
> > 1-13 ; 3116
> ```

But then when I put it into a graph, it's nonsense : the DayOfYear doesn't reflect a date so it is sorted in the wrong order

Any idea of how to do this? Should I keep the datetime format?

Comment: Are you already using `pandas`? And this will be much more fun to answer if you put in cut-and-pastable sample data.

Comment: Yes I'm using pandas, as for the data it's from a Kaggle competition so I'm not sure I'm allowed :(

Comment: ? but it's allowed to ask for help on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it :)

Instead of building a string for month-day I added a column with the datetime in format %M-%d

Then I've groupedby the data to count the number of items for each day of the year, and made a plot of the number of items from this groupedby data